# DXA 1.5 Search Integration Amazon

Tags: dxa, search, dxa-1.5, si4t, solr

I have implemented the Search Module with my DXA 1.5 application using this script:

```
.\web-install.ps1 -distDestination "D:\Projects\Site" -searchProviderType AwsCloudSearchProvider
```

And I have configured my endpoints in CMS, now my Components are indexed at Amazon cloud.

But when I search content in search box using DXA SearchModule I'm getting null reference error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

After debugging the code, I identified that `baseModelType` is null in below method

```
public Type GetModelTypeFromSemanticMapping(Type baseModelType)
```

in `SemanticSchema.cs` file.

Detailed Error

> ERROR - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   Sdl.Web.Common.Mapping.SemanticSchema.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.b__0(Type
>   t) in
>   D:\Projects\MPSDXAmeyankTest\Sdl.Web.Common\Mapping\SemanticSchema.cs:line
>   120    at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() 
>   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Common.Mapping.SemanticSchema.GetModelTypeFromSemanticMapping(Type
>   baseModelType) in
>   D:\Projects\MPSDXAmeyankTest\Sdl.Web.Common\Mapping\SemanticSchema.cs:line
>   120    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel&
>   entityModel, IComponent component, Type baseModelType, Localization
>   localization)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel(EntityModel&
>   entityModel, IComponentPresentation cp, Localization localization)
>   at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.ModelBuilderPipeline.CreateEntityModel(IComponentPresentation
>   cp, Localization localization)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Tridion.Mapping.DefaultModelBuilder.BuildPageModel(PageModel&
>   pageModel, IPage page, IEnumerable`1 includes, Localization
>   localization)

Any Guidelines will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That is weird. The `baseModelType` is obtained from the View Model Registry (the MVC data of the CT is resolved to a View Model Type), but is not expected to ever be `null`; in case the View Model Type cannot be resolved, an exception should be thrown.

I notice that you seem to be using a custom build of `Sdl.Web.Common`. Have you made any changes?

Since you are debugging already, you could backtrack to `DefaultModelBuilder.BuildEntityModel` where the (base) Model Type is determined and see where/how that becomes `null`.

Comment: Thanks for Reply i did not make any changes into dxa module after getting null reference error on view i debugged my code rather using compiled dlls.
one Question do we need to add new rout for SI4T search controller. seems request in not going to SearchController

Comment: No, you don't have to add a route; that is taken care of by the Search Module's AreaRegistration. The SearchController is an Entity Controller which is automatically invoked when the Search Results Page is requested.

Comment: BTW: in order to debug, you don't have to do a custom build; you can also obtain the DXA PDBs from the DXA Distribution.

Comment: under Search module area there is no AreaRegistration after installation of dxa search module shall i create manually ? or let me know any additional step to perform for search module to work

Comment: No additional steps are needed. Just run `web-install.ps1` like you mentioned (I assume that `D:\Projects\Site` is the root folder of your DXA Web App).  The installer deploys the Search Module Views and `Sdl.Web.Modules.Search.dll`. The presence of that DLL in your DXA Web App `bin` Folder is enough to make it work.

Comment: I have Re-Installed SearchModule i my DXA 1.5 solution  Now it gives me error 
No View Model registered for View 'TxxxxxC:Entity:SearchResult'. Check that you have registered this View in the 'TxxxxC' area registration.
Dxa searches View in my custom region any solution for this -- SearchResult view is inside Search Area

Comment: The View is sought in the Area/Module specified as metadata on the CT. The Search Results CT provided as part of the Search Module uses the `Search` Area, so it seems you are using something else. How did you install the Search Module in your CM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48382/discussion-between-rick-pannekoek-and-meyank).

Comment: I have resolved the CT issue thanks. but now it gives SI4T error while searching : Could not load file or assembly 'SI4T.Query, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Does that mean you got It working in the end? If so, can you summarize what the problems were so that other people might benefit?